# references, tables, figure title

Tags: endfloat

How to force  tables, figures, and notes to the end of the manuscript in latex? In the order of text, references, tables, figure titles, and grouped footnotes. I appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: If this is for a journal, they probably have a class. Use that.

Comment: @cfr unfortunately they do not

Comment: @gernot any suggestion ?

Comment: For floats, have a look at the `endfloat` package.

Comment: Why would i get this error " File `endfloat.sty" not found  when i use endfloat package ? @TorbjørnT. @cfr  I already extracted the file to my working directory.

Comment: Because it's not installed ... You can likely use the package manager of your TeX distribution (MikTeX/MacTeX/TeX Live) to install it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch the last part of that comment. If it's in the same folder as your `.tex` file, I can't say why it wouldn't work. In general it's better to install using the distributions package manager though. (Oh, and you can only ping one person per comment I think, so @cfr wouldn't have been notified of your previous comment.)

Comment: Which file did you extract? But use your package manager to install it instead, as @TorbjørnT. says.